# Text to Speech 37 byte file returned

Tags: ibm-watson

The wav file returned by the IBM Watson text to speech service is blank.

I have tried many command line arguments (including,excluding braces) and most return blank wav files of size 37 bytes. My OS is Windows 10.

```
curl -X POST -u "apikey:{my_key_number_here}" ^
--header "Content-Type: application/json" ^
--header "Accept: audio/wav" ^
--data "{\"text\":\"Hello world.\"}" ^
--output hello_world.wav ^
"https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api"
```

I would like to get a "hello world" wav file but instead the wav file I get is blank and only 37 bytes in size.

Comment: The 37 bytes will be an error code. Try taking a look at the response to see what the error is.

Comment: I opened up the file and it says {"code":401, "error": "Unauthorized"}

Answer (score 0):

It looks you don't have the complete URL in your Curl command. You need to use the URL `https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api/v1/synthesize`.

Comment: still getting the same blank file

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably still an incorrect url, as hinted at by Mike Kistler's answer. The 37 byte file will be an error code and based on your comments its a

```
{"code":401, "error": "Unauthorized"}
```

Which means that either you have the wrong key, or you are using the wrong endpoint. To obtain both you need to create an instance of the TTS service in IBM Cloud. Once created you can create credentials for the service. Take a look a the credentials, there will be an IAM Key as well as an endpoint. You need both. Endpoints differ according to the centre you deployed to. For example if you deployed on to the Frankfurt location the endpoint will be `https://stream-fra.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api`

Comment: It was the wrong apikey after all! Thank you so much for your help. Now it works.